# Enable whitespace in php regular expresssion

Tags: php, whitespace, preg-match, match, preg-match-all

I want to have A-Z, 0-9 and whitespace ignored in regular expression, currently I have this, it works but whitespaces are ignored too but I need them.

```
preg_match_all("/[^\w]/",$string,$matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` represents whitespace characters. So if you want to match every character except word characters (`\w`) or whitespace characters (`\s`), try this:

```
preg_match_all("/[^\w\s]/",$string,$matches);
```

Comment: thanks it works! I know that s is for that but I've put the s outside of the bracket lol :D thanks very much! But I have another problem I will edit my post.

Comment: @Cirk: What is part one and what the other part(s)?

Comment: :D I've posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174338/php-regex-ignore-and

Comment: @Cirk: Why don’t you ask just one question?

Comment: Well I wanted first, but I think it's better to make a new question for that.